Why doesn't DuckDB return data?
Considering this very simple function:
import duckdb from "duckdb";

const db = new duckdb.Database("./database/knowledge.duck");
const con = db.connect();

export const keyword_search = async (keywords) => {

    const test = await con.prepare(
        `
        SELECT id, content, score
        FROM ( SELECT *, fts_main_knowledge.match_bm25( id, '${keywords}' ) AS score FROM knowledge ) sq
        WHERE score IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY score DESC
        LIMIT 2;`).all();

    return test
};

I can't get results back. The only thing I get is:
RESULTS:  [
  Statement {
    sql: "\n\t\tSELECT id, content, score\n\t\tFROM ( SELECT *, fts_main_knowledge.match_bm25( id, 'hello' ) AS score FROM knowledge ) sq\n\t\tWHERE score IS NOT NULL\n\t\tORDER BY score DESC\n\t\tLIMIT 2;",
    run: [class run],
    all: [class all],
    arrowIPCAll: [class arrowIPCAll],
    each: [class each],
    finalize: [class finalize],
    stream: [class stream],
    columns: [class columns],
    get: [Function],
  }]

What am I missing to get data results?
I can log data but cannot return it when I store rows in an array:
const test = con.all(
    
    SELECT id, content, score
    FROM ( SELECT *, fts_main_knowledge.match_bm25( id, '${keywords}' ) AS score FROM knowledge ) sq
    WHERE score IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 2;`,
    (err, rows) => {
        if (err) return;
        console.log(rows)
    },
);

